# How to navigate to a alert using Selenium Web Driver with Java?

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2

I am trying to navigate the command on the alert box, but I am not able to do it in Web Driver with JAVA. Please help me with it. Apart from this I would also like to know how to tackle with the confirmation box and Warnings prompts displayed.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information to go by, please? How have you tried to access the alert box? What is the failure message? What's the code of the page generating the alert? Right now there isn't enough information for the Selenium folks to give you much help.

Comment: There is several different types of alerts. There can be pop up alerts, iframe alerts and many many other ways to alert the end user. The way that the alert is displayed will change the way that the alert is handled.

Comment: selenium 4 can now help you with basic authentication
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2021/a-tour-of-4-authentication/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a Javascript alert box, this is relatively straightforward; you can switch to it with `driver.switchTo().alert();` in Java. If you save the return value of that as an Alert object, you can interact with it, like `alert.accept()`. See [the javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html) for more information.

Since you're asking, however, I suspect it's not so simple. If this is not really an alert, but a popup that the browser has generated, such as a Basic Authentication prompt, you cannot interact with it using WebDriver, as WebDriver can only interact with things that exist in the DOM. You will have to use another Java library, such as [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), to interact with popups at this level.

Comment: @Swap if you are satisfied with this answer, please click the check button to indicate that you've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the given link for example:

1. [How To Handle JavaScript Confirm Box](http://reditblog.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-handle-javascript-confirm-box.html)
2. [How To Handle JavaScript Alert Box](http://reditblog.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-handle-javascript-alert-box.html)